# Issue a Part number from a list once

Tags: excel, vba

I want in a shared Excel document that contains a list of part numbers, when you click a button it grabs and prints an available part number from the list, marks it used, and never issues that part# again.
[image: layout picture]

"Sheet1" contains the Part #s and usage info.
Column A: Part#'s, Column B: Either 0 (available), 1(used)

"Sheet2" where the user obtains a part number.
A1 = part# ouput (user copies this)

```vb
Sub GenNumber()
    Dim PartNum As String
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range

    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B1000000")
    
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If rCell = 0 Then
            Set rCell.Value = 1
            PartNum = rCell.Offset(0, -1)
            Range("A1") = PartNum
            Exit For
        Else
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Part-Number Issued: " + PartNum
End Sub
```

Comment: How is this workbook going to be shared?  In a single-user-at-a-time location like a shared network folder, or somewhere like SharePoint where multiple users can use it at the same time?  I might not be too confident in the second scenario that it wouldn't be possible to two users to get the same number...

Answer (score 0):

It didn't run without these changes - does this help?

```
Sub GenNumber()
  Dim PartNum As String
  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim rRng As Range
  Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B1000")
  For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    If rCell.Value = 0 Then
      rCell.Value = 1
      PartNum = rCell.Offset(0, -1)
      Range("A1") = PartNum
      Exit For
    Else
    End If
  Next
  MsgBox "Part-Number Issued: " + PartNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks That did it, At least got me close enough to make it work! Really appreciate it!